# After mocking object there are missing functions?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Admittedly I am very new to working with Mock objects but have come across a strange behavior that I hope someone can explain to me.

I have two classes class A and class B. B extends A and looks something like this.

```
    abstract class A {

        private $property

        public __constructor( $arg ) {
                //sets and does constructor stuff
        }

        public function a() {
        //does stuff
    }

    public function b() {
        //does more stuff
    }

    public function c() {
        //calls b and does stuff
    }

}

class B extends A {

    const MyCONST = //some literal

    public __constructor() {
        parent::__constructor( self::MyCONST );
    }

}
```

Since my class A is abstract I am doing my testing on class B. When testing function c I need to stub function b so I have done the following in my test.

```
$objectUnderTest = $this->getMockBuilder( 'B' )
            ->setMethods( array( 'b' ) )
            ->getMock();

$objectUnderTest->expects( $this->once() )
        ->method( 'b' )
        ->will( $this->returnValue( 5 ) );

$result = $objectUnderTest->c();

//then some assertions
```

The problem I am running into is that when the following test code is executed PHPUnit it complains that it can not find method c of $objectUnderTest. Now from what I understand even if I had created the mock object incorrectly and function c had become a stub method as opposed to a mock method it would still be invokeable right? Some debugging to confirm what PHPUnit was telling me I outputted to the console the results of get_class_methods() on the mock object as well as on a normal instance of my class B. This is what it outputted for each.

```
//class B
array(
    (int) 0 => '__construct',
    (int) 1 => 'a',
    (int) 2 => 'b',
    (int) 3 => 'c'
)

//mocked B
array(
    (int) 0 => '__clone',
    (int) 1 => 'b',
    (int) 2 => 'expects',
    (int) 3 => 'staticExpects',
    (int) 4 => '__phpunit_getInvocationMocker',
    (int) 5 => '__phpunit_getStaticInvocationMocker',
    (int) 6 => '__phpunit_hasMatchers',
    (int) 7 => '__phpunit_verify',
    (int) 8 => '__phpunit_cleanup'
)
```

Does anyone know what happened to my other methods for this class or explain this behavior?

Comment: Just a side note here: Your `__construct()` in B violates strict standards, because it has not the same parameters than `__construct()` from A.

Comment: Would that cause the problem above or is that more of a coding preference?

Comment: This is why I said "side note" ;-) It has nothing to do with your problem, it just crashes your server if strict standards are enabled. But you will get a pretty clear error message in that case.

Comment: Hmmm I did not know that. Good to know.  But this code is really from a personal project that I'm working on and is going to be completely for private use so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Which version of PHPUnit are you using? About the side note: it actually depends on how one interprets Liskov substitution principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same problem while trying to run your code, so I included file with classes (A and B) to the test class. It helped me overcome this problem.

Comment: Now the code I posted above for the classes, each class is actually in its own file. And in the test class I had only included Class B, so you think this caused this problem even though B.php includes A.php itself? I just want to verify before I mark the post as solved.

Comment: I presumed that test class didn't contain include of A and B classes at all. My demo with your include options is still working so I don't have a clue about reason of your issue. Sorry for inconvenience.